# how to return a c++ pointer in objective-c function

Tags: c++, objective-c

In .mm file

```
#import "OCClass.h"
#import "CPPClass.h"

@interface OCClass()
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) CPPClass* cppClass;
@end

@implementation OCClass
-(void*)getObject
{
    return cppClass;
}
@end
```

The getObject method is a public method, it is defined in the header, and I want to return the cppClass object with the type of CPPClass* instead of void*. But I can't include a cpp header in objective-c header. How should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just forward declare the C++ class in your Objective-C .h file:

```
// OCClass.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

class CPPClass;

@interface OCClass : NSObject

-(CPPClass*)getObject;

@end
```

That way, you don't have to include the C++ .h file in your Objective-C .h file, and everything will still compile and work correctly. (Note that you can only `#import` this header file into a .mm file.) Also, your getObject method should either be:

```
-(CPPClass*)getObject
{
    return self.cppClass;
}
```

or

```
-(CPPClass*)getObject
{
    return _cppClass;
}
```

depending on whether you want to call the getter or not.

Comment: Hi! Having trouble getting this to compile if, for instance, CPPClass is inside a namespace.